# How to ignore files/folders using SVN in PHPstorm

Tags: svn, version-control, phpstorm, ignore

I want to create a new repository but don't want to include folders with cachefiles etc. I tried everything but it keeps committing all files and folders. In my project overview the folders are marked as 'ignored' for SVN and when doing a initial import I uncheck the box for committing ignored files/folders.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the fact that on the PHPStorm web site version control helps I can find no mention of "*the box for committing ignored files/folders*"

It sounds like you are:

1. Setting a load of files/directories up as ignored
2. Starting a commit but
3. **Not** including .svnignore in the commit
4. finding your ignores are ignored.

The problem is that svn stores the details of what to ignore in a file called `.svnignore` which, if you would like your ignores to be persistent and common to all users, **has to be committed itself.**

### Update

I think that the process that best fits your use case here is as follows, (sorry if I am teaching grandma to suck eggs), assuming that your bare repository already exists and has a standard structure like:

```
URL/trunk
URL/tags
URL/branches
```

This is the general process with the command line tools but can be adapted:

```
mkdir a_new_directory
svn co URL/trunk a_new_directory
cd a_new_directory
```

Copy the directory structure of your project to here including the ones you would like to ignore, (no files just the directories).
In a text file list the relative path of all the directories you would like to ignore, one per line, each with forward slashes if you are no windows and all ending with a forward slash:

```
svn propset svn:ignore -F the_text_file.txt
```

If you have some file types that you would like to universally ignore, e.g. .bat and .obj files:

```
svn proprev svn:ignore -R *.bat
svn proprev svn:ignore -R *.obj
```

I personally put a dir_info.txt file with a description of each directory into that directory and add them.

svn add all the directories, (and dir_info.txt files), then commit.

Then add your files to the directories, svn add them and commit.

Comment: The box is called 'included ignored resources' and I was thinking it has something to do with ignored folders. I agree on the .svnignore but I don't get a chance from PHPstorm to only commit these details and it starts committing entire cache and library dirs.

Comment: Sounds like: a) Bug report on PHPstorm & b) Use TortoiseSVN or the command line client svn + a text editor to set up your ignores and do the initial commit and then try using PHPStorm once your repository is up and running.

Comment: I think what i'm trying to do is against the nature of subversion but was possible using some sort of hack in Netbeans. Worked around it by submitting everything, ignoring dirs and removing then backwards from the repo. Thnx for looking into this.