# Ignore directory in SVN with PHPStorm does not work

Tags: svn, phpstorm, ignore

I was trying to add some directories to ignored list in SVN using the PHPstorm integration, but apparently, this is not working.

I'm following the instructions [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-ignored-files.html)
These is my ignored files/directories:

[image: Configure Ignored Files screen]

Here is my Default ChangeList to check all files to commit:
[image: Changes to commit]

As you can see, the .idea / directory should be ignored, but appears in the list to be sent. Someone know what I'm doing wrong?

I found [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299358/how-to-ignore-files-folders-using-svn-in-phpstorm) [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116074/how-to-ignore-a-directory-with-svn) in SO, but didn't find answer in any of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issue in previous times. I used [tortoise svn](http://tortoisesvn.net/) to ignore folder and files that I wish. Only then phpstorm recognized ignored items.

Comment: It works like a charm! Perhaps this issue is a bug of PHPStorm.